# 7zip error - can not open output file

Tags: archive

I am trying to unzip a 7zip file from the command line like this, but I get an error with using e or x parameters. The file has only 1 .dat file inside. I get the following error.

```
valugi@valugi-desktop:/$ 7z x /var/www/site/data/7zip/eu/
Processing archive: /var/www/site/data/7zip/eu/file.7z
can not open output file file.dat
Skipping    file.dat

Sub items Errors: 1
```

I can open the file if I am opening it with the File Roller desktop application, but I want to use the command line, as I want to integrate this into a PHP script.

How can I find out what is generating this error and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is here:

```
valugi-desktop:/$
```

You are on the root directory, you will need superuser privileges to write to var.

Just try:

```
sudo 7z x /var/www/site/data/7zip/eu/
```

Or,if the script is going to be called by another user.

```
sudo -u username 7z x /var/www/site/data/7zip/eu/
```

Comment: I think you are right. I will not do sudo as my script gets executed by www-data and I think this user is allowed there.. thanks

Comment: sudo -u www-data 7z... will let you test it them.

Answer (score 1):

The part about "`can not open output file`" suggests writing the target file is a problem.

1. Check that you have sufficient space in the output directory to take the unzipped file.
2. Confirm compressed file integrity with "`7z t /var/www/site/data/7zip/eu/file.7z`"

   - this second point is probably just for your confirmation.

Comment: yes. I guess is the user group or the file permissions that I have to change. thanks